# CheckMarx Stored XSS Fix in C# for DataSet and DataReader

Tags: c#, dataset, xss, datareader, checkmarx

After doing the CheckMarx scan for our legacy ASP.NET Application, we got some vulnerabilities under Stored XSS mentioning the issues in SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet object) and SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() methods. Upon researching for the fix in the above 2 methods we have not got any proper solution since those 2 methods are the very common .Net Methods.

Does any one faced the same problem and fixed the Stored XSS issue in SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet object) and SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() methods. Please update us with the solution and added the code reference below:

1.)  **SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet object):**

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  da.Fill(ds);
```

2.)  **SqlCommand.ExecuteReader():**

```
 SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(con, commandText);
 cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: does checkmarx show these lines as the sink or the source? there's a data flow diagram in Checkmarx that shows where the potential tainted data and where it would render. I don't think this is where the sink is. I think this is more of the source. Show us where the data flows at the end

Comment: DataSet allFilter = SitSql.GetDataSet(commandText);
                    GridView.DataSource = allFilter;
                    GridView.DataBind();

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided that the ASP.NET web application you're working on is legacy, I assume you're not using any Razor templating engine like most modern versions of ASP.NET utilize that would have automatically encoded the data rendered.

You will have to then escape each cell of data using Server.HtmlEncode method (or HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode) in the GridView's ItemDataBound event:

```
  void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
        
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = Server.HtmlEncode(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);        
    }
    
  } 

      <asp:gridview id="GridView" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound" 
        runat="server">
      </asp:gridview>
```

After implementing this code change, Checkmarx might not be able to create a data flow with this event so you will have to deliberate this with your AppSec team and show that data is escaped before it is presented on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the update and one more query...is there any encoding techniques available in .Net for DataSet and DataReader objects at Source places instead of doing the encoding at the destination places where we are doing the data bindings...i mean is there any encoding techniques available at below 2 places:

1.)  
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 da.Fill(ds);
 
 2.)  
 SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(con, commandText);
 cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: i don't think there is. you have to go into the weeds of the dataset to encode each data.